# NSHTTPURLResponse release message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I have the following code to get data from server;

```
 -(void)loginForFaceBook
  {


         GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController;
         viewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc]
          initWithScope:@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"
          clientID:@"27615...6qdi60qjmachs.apps.googleusercontent.com"

            clientSecret:@"Fs8A...u2PH"

                                                     keychainItemName:@"OAuth2 Sample:    
             Google+"
                                                             delegate:self

       finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];

       [[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController
                                           animated:YES];


      }


  - (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController
        finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                  error:(NSError *)error {



     if (error != nil) {
         // Authentication failed (perhaps the user denied access, or closed the
        // window before granting access)
         NSLog(@"Authentication error: %@", error);
         NSData *responseData = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"data"]; //   
         kGTMHTTPFetcherStatusDataKey
          if ([responseData length] > 0) {
             // show the body of the server's authentication failure response
 //                 NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData
 //                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  //            NSLog(@"%@", str);
    }

 //        self.auth = nil;
      } else {
 //            NSString *authCode = [NSString alloc]in;
         NSMutableURLRequest * request;
         request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL    
         URLWithString:@"http://api.kliqmobile.com/v1/tokens"]

        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                       timeoutInterval:60] ;
          NSLog(@"%@",auth);
          NSLog(@"ho gya success %@ :::: %@ :::: %@", auth.accessToken, 
          auth.refreshToken, auth.code);
          NSMutableURLRequest * response;
         NSError             * error;

          request.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.kliqmobile.com/v1/tokens"];
           NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  
          {\"token\":\"%@\",\"secret\":\"%@\",\"service\":\"%@\",\"handle\":\"%@\"}",   
           auth.accessToken,auth.code,@"google",nil];
            NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding   
             allowLossyConversion:YES];
            NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
             [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  
             forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
         [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
         [request setHTTPBody:postData];
        error       = nil;
        response    = nil;

          NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request 
         delegate:self];
         [connection start];

  }
```

I have implemented the `NSURLConnection` delegtes method and data is printing well like this

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
{
    NSMutableURLRequest * response;
    NSError             * error;
    NSLog(@"Did Receive Data %@", [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data
                                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    NSMutableURLRequest * requestContacts;
    requestContacts = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL
                                                                URLWithString:@"http://api.kliqmobile.com/v1/contacts"]

                                                   cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                               timeoutInterval:60] ;
    [requestContacts setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [requestContacts setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
    error       = nil;
    response    = nil;

    NSData* data1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestContacts
                                          returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSLog(@"WE GET THE REQUIRED TOKAN DATA %@ :: %@ :: %@", [[NSString alloc]
                                                             initWithData:data1 encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding], error ,response);



}
```

but after that my app get crashed and it is giving following error;

> [NSHTTPURLResponse release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xcb51070.

please suggest me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

1. What is the intent of your `didReceiveData` method? There are a bunch of issues here:

   - You really shouldn't be doing a synchronous network request in the middle of a `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` method.
   - You shouldn't be doing synchronous requests at all, but rather do them asynchronously.
   - What is the connection between receiving data and your creation of this new request? You're not using the data in the request, so why do it here?

   The typical pattern is:

   - The `didReceiveResponse` should instantiate a `NSMutableData` object in some class property.
   - The only function of `didReceiveData` should be to append the received data to the `NSMutableData`. Note, this method may be called multiple times before all the data is received.
   - In `connectionDidFinishLoading`, you should initiate any next steps that you take upon successful completion of the request. If you wanted to do start another asynchronous network request when the initial request is done, do that here.
   - In `didFailWithError`, you obviously handle any failure of the connection.
2. When you call `connectionWithRequest`, you should not use the `start` method. Only use `start` when you use `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:` with `NO` for the `startImmediately` parameter. Otherwise the connection starts automatically for you and you're only starting it a second time.
3. Unrelated to your original question, but your creation of `post` string cannot be right. You're missing a parameter value. Even better, rather than creating JSON manually, use `NSDictionary` and then use `NSJSONSerialization` to make the `NSData` object containing the JSON from this dictionary. That's much safer:

   ```
   NSDictionary *params = @{@"token"   : auth.accessToken, 
                            @"secret"  : auth.code, 
                            @"service" : @"google",
                            @"handle"  : @""};
   NSError *error;
   NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:0 error:&error];
   ```

   Clearly, supply whatever you need for the `handle` value.
4. A tangential process-related observation, but I'm wondering if you're taking advantage of everything Xcode offers. For example, your declaration of `response` as a `NSMutableURLRequest` but then using that as a parameter to `sendSynchronousRequest` should have generated a compiler warning. The same thing is true with your `stringWithFormat` for your `post` string (my third point). That should have generated a warning, too.

   Neither of these are immediately relevant, but I wonder if you are failing to heed any other compile-time warnings. These warnings are your best friend when writing robust code and I would recommend resolving all of them. To go a step further, you should also run the project through the static analyzer ("Analyze" on "Product" menu, or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>), and resolve anything it points out, too.